# How to Customize UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

How to customize UITabBarItem, like Instangram app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, The UITabBar can not be customised. But if you want to customise it, you can add a layer containing an UIButton with the UIImage you want on the top.